# Servlet Program works only for first time

Tags: java, servlets

I was trying this small `HttpSession` program as a demo for my project.
This program just checks whether the user is new, if it is then displays a `form`, if the user is not new, then it displays the name of the user, the `color` he selected and the total no. of visits.

When i run my program, it works only for the first time. That means when i run another instance of my program, it displays a blank web page.

What is wrong in the code that is causing this problem???

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;


public class SessionServlet extends HttpServlet {

protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
    try (PrintWriter out = response.getWriter()) {
        Integer hitCount;
        HttpSession s = request.getSession(true);            
        if(s.isNew()) {
            out.println("<!DOCTYPE html>");
            out.println("<html>");
            out.println("<head>");
            out.println("<title>Servlet SessionServlet</title>");            
            out.println("</head>");
            out.println("<body>");

            out.println("<form method=get action=SessionServlet>");
            out.println("<h3>Please sleect a Color</h3>");
            out.println("<input type=radio name=color />Red");
            out.println("<br /><input type=radio name=color />Green");
            out.println("<br /><input type=text name=txtName />");
            out.println("<br /><input type=submit name=Submit value=Submit />");
            out.println("</form>");

            out.println("</body>");
            out.println("</html>");
        } else if(!s.isNew()){
            String name = (String) request.getParameter("txtName");
            String color = (String) request.getParameter("color");
            hitCount = new Integer(1);
            s.setAttribute("Name", name);
            s.setAttribute("color", color);
            s.setAttribute("HitCount", hitCount);
            if((name != null) && (color != null)) {
                out.println("Name: " + s.getAttribute("Name"));
                hitCount = (Integer)s.getAttribute("HitCount");
                hitCount = hitCount++;
                s.setAttribute("HitCount", hitCount);
                //out.println("<body bgcolor=" + s.getAttribute("color") + ">");
                out.println("you selected" + s.getAttribute("color"));
                out.println("Total visits=====>" + s.getAttribute("HitCount"));
            }
        }
    }
}  
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **second** time you run this code, the session already exists, so the program goes through *else* branch- but the "old" *request* object (from the **first** run of the application) and its parameters (*color* and *name*) are already gone at that time. Request is destroyed by container right after the *response* from the first application run was sent back to the client.

In your code

`String name = (String) request.getParameter("txtName");
String color = (String) request.getParameter("color");`

you are trying to get non existing parameters. Parameters *txtName* and *color* do not exist in *request* anymore. Therefore they are null and the next condition

`if((name != null) && (color != null))`

is always *false*. And nothing is written into *out* Writer.

What you should do in order to make this work is to read the parameters from the *session* object (this is what the sessions are made for anyway) where you should put them in the first application run. This code won't work. And your *hitCount* will always be 1 (please see *HttpSessionListener* interface). This code is wrong on so many levels- you should re-write everything after the `else if` branch which should be only `else` anyway.

**TLDR:
Your question was why it is not working: the answer is - you are reading non existing parameters. You have to put the parameters into *session* object in the first application run and read them from it.**

### edit after your question from December 31st:

Here is what I would do. Assume following directory structure of this simple project named **SessionServlet**. This structure will be used in whole answer. To simplify things I won't list every directory, you surely get the idea from this. This is *not* the real-life example of directory structure, it is simplified for the purposes of this tutorial example.

```
<path-to-project>/SessionServlet/src/com/example/session
<path-to-project>/SessionServlet/WebContent/META-INF
<path-to-project>/SessionServlet/WebContent/WEB-INF
```

Create an *html* file, for example **start.html**. It should contain the input fields which values you need to store in the session. The file goes here

```
<path-to-project>/SessionServlet/WebContent/start.html
```

Its contents

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Start page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="get" action="MySessionServlet">
       <h3>Please select a Color</h3>
       <input type="radio" name="color" value="red" />Red<br>
       <input type="radio" name="color" value="green" />Green<br>
       <input type="text" name="txtName" /><br>
       <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

In your servlet example you forgot the *value* attribute in radiobutton input, therefore whichever radiobutton you would check, the value would be *on*, not the color name.

Next you have to create the servlet class **SessionServlet.java**, which will be slightly different from your original idea. It goes here:

```
<path-to-project>/SessionServlet/src/com/example/session/SessionServlet.java
```

Its contents

```
package com.example.session;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

public class SessionServlet extends HttpServlet {

   private static final long serialVersionUID = -3808675281434686897L;

   @Override
   public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
       String requestColor = null;
       String requestTxtName = null;

       PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
       MySessionListener listener = new MySessionListener();
       HttpSession session = request.getSession();

       if (session.isNew()) {
           //these are request parameters sent from html form
           requestColor = request.getParameter("color");
           requestTxtName = request.getParameter("txtName");

           //save the attributes in session in order to use them later
           session.setAttribute("sessionColor", requestColor);
           session.setAttribute("sessionTxtName", requestTxtName);
       }
       else {
           //get the previously stored attributes from session
           String color = (String) session.getAttribute("sessionColor");
           String name = (String) session.getAttribute("sessionTxtName");

           //session info
           out.println("session already existed");

           if (color != null && name != null) {
               out.println("Name: " + name);
               out.println("Color: " + color);

               out.println("Session count: " + listener.getSessionCount());
           }
       }
   }
}
```

I think the servlet's code is pretty much self-explanatory. However, if you have any particular questions, please ask.

In order to count the active sessions, you need to create a SessionListener class and count the sessions. For the purposes of this example I put the class into the same directory as servlet class. Please do not do this in real project. You'd create a big mess. This is only simplified Java Enterprise *Hello world* example. The file is here

```
<path-to-project>/SessionServlet/src/com/example/session/MySessionListener.java
```

Its contents are

```
package com.example.session;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpSessionEvent;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSessionListener;

public class MySessionListener implements HttpSessionListener {

    private static int sessionCount;

    @Override
    public void sessionCreated(HttpSessionEvent se) {
        System.out.println("Creating session with id: " + se.getSession().getId());
        sessionCount++;
    }

    @Override
    public void sessionDestroyed(HttpSessionEvent se) {
        System.out.println("Destroying session id: " + se.getSession().getId());
        sessionCount--;
    }

    public int getSessionCount() {
        return sessionCount;
    }
}
```

The listener class for counting active sessions must implement *HttpSessionListener* interface. We call the method *getSessionCount()* in SessionServlet class as you already noticed.

The last thing to do is to create a deployment descriptor xml in order to tell the container what to do with those classes we created.
the file **must** be named web.xml and it **must** be placed in WEB-INF directory.

```
<path-to-project>/SessionServlet/WebContent/WEB-INF/web.xml
```

Its contents are

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
        id="WebApp_ID"
        version="3.1">

   <display-name>SessionServlet</display-name>

   <welcome-file-list>
       <welcome-file>start.html</welcome-file>
   </welcome-file-list>

   <servlet>
       <servlet-name>my Session Servlet</servlet-name>
       <servlet-class>com.example.session.SessionServlet</servlet-class>
   </servlet>

   <servlet-mapping>
       <servlet-name>my Session Servlet</servlet-name>
       <url-pattern>/MySessionServlet</url-pattern>
   </servlet-mapping>

   <!-- set session timeout to 30 minutes -->
   <session-config>
       <session-timeout>30</session-timeout>
   </session-config>

   <!-- register listener class -->
   <listener>
       <listener-class>com.example.session.MySessionListener</listener-class>
   </listener>
</web-app>
```

And that's all. Lastly my two cents- you should first acquaint with Standard Edition Java. This is an example from Enterprise world which is way over your head yet. There are plenty of tutorials on the web. Give it some time, you won't regret it.

Regarding the servlets- you should (must) first understand the basic concepts of request, response, session, client and container (who is who, the lifecycle, managing, etc.) before you start making real projects. The best book I've seen about this is Head First - Servlets and JSP, which should be a starting point in understanding this topic.

Comment: I am still not able to get it working :(
Can you post only the general code for doing this or give me some link?

Comment: This means that The web page build using index.html file cannot be made within the servlet container as in my program?

Comment: It cannot be in the same servlet the way you designed it. It can be in another servlet and then redirected to this second servlet. But it is much simpler to create html file than create the html file using java code (Even simple html pages would be quite difficult to write as a servlet). It is bad design anyway. The servlet serves as a controller (you probably heard of MVC). Servlet shouldn't contain any business logic and any presentation data.

Answer (score 1):

You set `response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8")` ....

But in your section `if(!s.isNew()){....` the output is not HTML, but is plain text. ("`Name:`", etc...)

My bet is that the content is there, but your browser is not displaying it.

Comment: ie, when `s.isNew() == true`

Comment: @Adil when `s.isNew()==true` you output html.  when it is false, you output text